# python remove duplicate value in dictionary and change key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to remove the duplicate value in a complicated dictionary

```
a = {0:{'time':11}, 1:{'time':12}, 2:{'time':12}, 3:{'time':13}}
```

is there any way to remove 2:{'time':12}, and get

```
b = {0:{'time':11}, 1:{'time':12}, 2:{'time':13}}
```

my code is

```
m = {}
for key, value in a.items():
    if key == 0:
        m[0] = value
elif a[key] != a[key -1]:
    m[key] = value
```

but the result is `{0: {'time': 11}, 1: {'time': 12}, 3: {'time': 13}}`
I am wondering if there is any way to get the result as dict b, and if there is any way to do this faster, because I have a lot of data to deal with. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Your code is *very very wrong*. Dictionary key-value pairs are not ordered, your code works so only by happenstance!

Comment: The problem is that a dictionary doesn't imply an order, as you seem to ask for. To implement something that may work for you, you must specify what the the sorting key is in you case. It seems that your key 3 should become key 2 in dictionary b. How is the order supposed to be?

Answer (score 3):

First let's create a list of all times:

```
>>> c = [a[k]['time'] for k in sorted(a)]
>>> c
[11, 12, 12, 13]
```

Then lets use `groupby` to group by consecutive equal values:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> d = [x for x, y in groupby(c)]
>>> d
[11, 12, 13]
```

Now we can zip the keys with the new values and create a dictionary:

```
 >>> dict(zip(sorted(a), d))
 {0: 11, 1: 12, 2: 13}
```

We can combine all steps:

```
>>> keys = sorted(a)
>>> dict(zip(keys, (x for x, y in groupby(a[k]['time'] for k in keys))))
{0: 11, 1: 12, 2: 13}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do `groupby` on the items `sorted` by the `time` value, then `enumerate` into a dictionary

```
from itertools import groupby

a = {0:{'time':11}, 1:{'time':12}, 2:{'time':12}, 3:{'time':13}}
b = dict(enumerate(next(i[1])[1] for i in
          groupby(sorted(a.items(),
                         key=lambda i: i[1]['time']),
                         lambda i: i[1]['time'])))
```

`b` is now

```
{0: {'time': 11}, 1: {'time': 12}, 2: {'time': 13}}
```

though I seriously question the usability of such a structure for this kind of task.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove elements from a dict with `pop`, and assign them with the `myDict[key]` syntax so this is simply

```
a = {0:{'time':11}, 1:{'time':12}, 2:{'time':12}, 3:{'time':13}}
a[2] = a.pop(3)
a = {0: {'time': 11}, 1: {'time': 12}, 2: {'time': 13}}
```

From the example though it is unclear that this is the right way to organize your dictionary for your task. For example if the only values in your dictionary are `{'time': <someNumber>}` why not simply have the value be the `someNumber`?

Also as noted elsewhere looping over a dictionary where ordering is needed is a very bad idea as elements are not guaranteed to be in the order you think they are.

Comment: Even if the most correct way of using a dictionary, that doesn't change the other key-value-pairs though.

Comment: it reassigns the value for key `2`

Comment: Thank you!. For example if the only values in your dictionary are {'time': <someNumber>} why not simply have the value be the someNumber? because there are other elements in the dictionary like {'time': 12, 'mass', 23324}, I also need key as a numbering.

Comment: OK then that makes a bit more sense. I'l edit to reflect that. Assuming there are duplicate times which have different masses which one would you prefer to keep?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the value as a separate dictionary item could you instead use a tuple?  For example, your key could be 1, 2, etc. and your value ('time',11) or ('time',12).  I'm really assuming that your values are not going to be changed so an immutable data type like tuple could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a reversed mapping to the minimal index:

```
for k, v in a.iteritems():
    key = v['time']
    # we want the minimal index of the item
    reverse_mapping[key] = min(v, reverse_mapping.get(key, k))
```

Now reverse the mapping again after you've filtered needless items:

```
reversed_original = {v: k for k, v in reverse_mapping.iteritems()}
```

Now create a new list of items based on filtered list and use the dict constructor to restore a `dict` from it:

```
result = dict([(x, {'time': v[1]}) for x, v in enumerate(
    sorted(reversed_original.iteritems())
)])
```

Output:

```
{0: {'time': 11}, 1: {'time': 12}, 2: {'time': 13}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is probably not what you want for this kind of task. Instead, use a heap priority queue, which is an efficient, self-ordering alternative, depending on some key of your choice.
[python.org – Heap queue algorithm](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html)